# How do I get a CTE to work in my python code?

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a CTE that works when executed in sql server, but when I try to add it to my python script it doesn't work. The inner query of the CTE does work in my code, but when I have the CTE logic I get the error: `ProgrammingError: No results`.  Previous SQL was not a query.

I've played around with the formatting in python to no avail.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''With CTE as 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY concat(id , "cust.id") ORDER BY concat(id , "cust.id")) AS DupCount
FROM [dbo].[opport_test_table]
)
delete from CTE where DupCount > 1;''')

row = cursor.fetchone() 

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

I expect the output to delete records that are greater than 1 from the table.

Comment: There isn't anything special about Python here, apart from perhaps the `;` delimiter (but I wouldn't expect that to be the cause here either), because `cursor.execute()` only executes a single statement and so no statement delimiters are required.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are fetching rows however. A `delete` statement, with or without a CTE, *doesn't produce results*.

Comment: The error message `Previous SQL was not a query` seems to be giving you a hint.

Comment: What happens when you run that SQL directly against your database instance?

Comment: When i execute it against my database it works as excepted. When I comment out the                                                                                                           
 row = cursor.fetchone() 

for row in cursor:
    print(row)                                                                                                                The code works, but it doesn't delete any records from the table.

Comment: Does your code do the job, i.e. deleting the records. Do you expect it to do anything else (e.g. fetching data)?

Comment: Just delete the data from the database via python without me having to do it in sql server myself.

Comment: Did you try turning it into a stored procedure? The ";" caused me problems.